# Disqus Recent Comments Widget

Tags: javascript, widget, blogger, disqus

Do you know why this script is detected as document.write() on Lighthouse?

And is it possible to use DOM Manipulation or any alternative ways to solve this problem?

```
<script src="https://MyDisqusID.disqus.com/recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=4&hide_avatars=0&avatar_size=32&excerpt_length=200"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`recent_comments_widget.js` is no longer supported by Disqus but as a workaround you can use the public API to get recent comments https://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/list/ using any time parameters you prefer, then display the comment data into your document using plain JavaScript.

Comment: Better to say it's not maintained? It still works.

Answer (score 0):

When I searched on this to get the recent comments displaying, I found an example that works. Not relevant to your issue, but it's related somehow. From which I can say that Disqus still supports this.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gregorys-blog.disqus.com/recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=10&hide_avatars=0&avatar_size=40&excerpt_length=100"></script>
```

Just replace `gregorys-blog` with your own Disqus site.

More reference at: https://www.gregoryalexander.com/blog/2019/10/7/Building-your-own-Disqus-Recent-Comments-Widget